# How do you insert the values of variables made in a p5.js sketch into a MySQL database?

Tags: javascript, mysql, json, p5.js

I have made a sketch in p5.js which the user can manipulate in ways such as creating shapes and dragging them across the screen and controlling a slider. I was wondering if there was a way to insert things like the x and y coordinates of the shapes, their heights and widths, and the position of the scrollbar into a database in MySQL so that I could make a fully functioning site where users can create their sketches, save them and modify them.

I have tried using a JSON file but I have realized that I cannot modify JSON files using p5.js so a user would not be able to modify their sketches and save the changes. I have also searched the web for solutions to this problem but nothing seems to come up.

Comment: ___One possible way___ You send the JSON to an intermediate script, that would use PHP for example. That writes to the database. and you communicate using AJAX. You can also call via AJAX a script in PHP that will read the database and create a new JSON string and then send that back to the browser

Answer (score 1):

To interact with a database, you're going to need to run server-side code.

Your P5.js sketch (which is client-side code) would send a request to your server, and your server would store the data in a database.

There are many many many ways to write server code, and listing them all here would not be feasible. Instead, I recommend you start by trying out a few different options: PHP was listed, but there are also Java servers (using JavaEE) and JavaScript servers (using node.js).

Shameless self-promotion:

- [Here](https://happycoding.io/tutorials/java-server/client-server) is a tutorial on client-server communication, specifically JavaScript and Java servlets.
- [Here](https://github.com/KevinWorkman/p5-appengine-circles) is a repo that contains a P5.js sketch that stores data in Datastore.